# JFXPanel in Netbeans Swing Builder

Tags: java, swing, javafx, netbeans

I've been looking on the Internet if its possible to use the JFXPanel container in the Netbeans Swing Builder for a project that I'm currently working on. The only evidence that I've found that it is possible is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW2mq.png) picture - at the top-right hand side of the image, one can see that there is a component titled "JFXPanel" under the Swing Containers heading. Could somebody please point me in the direction to use this component in the Swing Builder? I do know how to add components to the Netbeans palette but I've just been unable to find this particular component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did some browsing in the jdk file on my C drive. The .jar I was looking for is titled "jfxrt.jar" and is located on my system at "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar"